# porting ruby scripts to arm processor

Tags: ruby

How to port ruby scripts to arm processor?

Answer (score 8):

ruby scripts are platform independent. they run over an interpreter.
what you need is to port the ruby interpreter to arm and then execute your scripts on it.
try search for a precompiled ruby interpreter for arm or search for how to compile it on arm processors.